# How to validate more than one form in same page without changing JS validation format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I currently have a JSP page that contains two forms:

```
<body>
   <form id="1"></form>
   <form id="2"></form>
</body>
```

**Only one form will be showing at the time when viewing the page.**

There is a JS validation file that is being used to check the form integrity when submit.
To simply put, this JS file cannot be changed. Whenever the JS file is being called, the core function takes in the form.

```
function validateForm(formToValidate){}
```

The validation result alert is a JSP page `id="alertMessage"`, being hidden at the beginning by CSS:

```
#alertMessage {
  display: none;
}
```

When any validation error happens, the page turns to visible by simple jQuery: `$("#alertMessage").show();`

The CSS requires the `id="alertMessage"` to not display the alert JSP page, and the JS requires the `id="alertMessage"` to do validation, and show alert messages.

Since I am having two forms in the page and the forms contain different content for validation, I have to include two JSP alerts in my page.

```
<body>
   <jsp:include page="alert for form 1">
   <form id="1"></form>

   <jsp:include page="alert for form 2">
   <form id="2"></form>
</body>
```

The issue:
Not only I am having duplicate ids `id="alertMessage"` in one page, it is always the first JSP alert page being picked. So even I am submitting form 2, the alert for form 1 will be triggered. Combing the alerts into one JSP alert page is not an option due to my design limitation.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Pass `id` of the form while validating and have `error-class` as child of the form for each `form`

Comment: Don't have duplicate IDs, they're supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

These slight modifications should help you.

Pass the form id in the function `validateForm(formToValidate)` as `formToValidate` parameter.

Remove the id tag from the error message containers. Add `class="alertMessage"` as attribute to the same.

Instead of `$("#alertMessage").show();` use `$("#"+formToValidate+" .alertMessage").show();`. Define the style for the class `.alertMessage` as below

```
.alertMessage {
  display: none;
}
```